# How to do OpenLayers map height 100% on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dictionary, openlayers

I want to 100% of the height.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="map" 
              style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/mq64pksd/). The pixel size is worjking for height but persentage(%) size is not working.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but look at setting maxExtent in OpenLayers, if you want to adjust how the map shows in terms of width/height.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try position fixed or absolute.

```
<div id="map" 
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:fixed">
</div>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` did not work for me, but `position:absolute` did the trick